# Appending creation date on filename

Tags: bash, date

I am trying to rename by adding creation(not modified)timestamp at the front of all the files(folders not included) in the directories and sub-directories with bash script.
I got this bash from one of my post.But that current bash won't print creation date.

```
for f in $(find . -type f); do    
    mv -T "$f" "${f%/*}/$(date -r "$f" +"%Y %m %d %H %M %S"|sed -e 's/   /_/g')_"${f##*/}""
done
```

Comment: See: [Get file created/creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24441/74329)

Comment: Why did you tag C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following bash command:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(dirname "$1")/$(stat -c %w "$1" | sed "s/\([^.]*\).*/\1/;s/[-: ]/_/g")_$(basename "$1")"' _ {} \;
```

`find` looks for all regular file and rename using `mv` each file found.

The filename is built such that it gets the creation time appended at the beginning of the file.

In order to get the file creation time, I use `stat` with option `-c %w` instead of `date -r` that gives the modification time.

The `sed` command replaces the output from `stat` to the wanted format (with `_`).

Comment: It doesn't work for me because _ append infront of filename instead of creation date.

Comment: @ZinOo It's likely because your filesystem doesn't support file creation timestamp. Look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created

Comment: On macos I had to replace `stat` with `gstat` (GNU Stat), thus what worked for me was: `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(dirname "$1")/$(gstat -c %w "$1" | sed "s/\([^.]*\).*/\1/;s/[-: ]/_/g")_$(basename "$1")"' _ {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Use date -r instead of stat...

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(dirname "$1")/$(date -r "$1" +%F | sed "s/\([^.]*\).*/\1/;s/[-: ]/_/g")_$(basename "$1")"' _ {} \;
```